# Optimizing calls for reauthentication by caching tokens and cookies

Tags: c#, asynchronous, rest, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I am currently developing a REST service in ASP.NET Core 2.2 that acts as a wrapper upon a REST API provided by a reporting solution.

The reporting systems REST API authenticates the user based on a username and a password and subsequent requests must contain both a token and the cookies received during the authentication process.

> My primary goal is optimize the traffic by caching tokens and cookies
>   for similar requests (that use the same reporting project which has
>   its own REST API instance) and reuse them until their expiration.
>
> My secondary goal is to write a class that is very easy to consume by
>   the controller which does not have even know about authentication and
>   retrials.

I am using [Api Client Generation Tools](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=dmitry-pavlov.ApiClientGenerationTools) to automatically generate the code used for actual REST API calls (type MsiRestClient).

#### The client service

```
public class MsiRestClientService : IMsiRestClientService
{
    #region Constants
    private const int TokenRefreshCoolDownPeriod = 30;  // seconds
    #endregion

    #region Variables
    private static readonly object LockSync = new object();

    private static readonly SemaphoreSlim GetNewTokenSemaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(1, 1);

    /// <summary>
    /// stores all the tokens generated for each project source
    /// </summary>
    private static readonly Dictionary<string, TokenInfo> MsiProjectSourceToTokenMap = new Dictionary<string, TokenInfo>();

    private static readonly Dictionary<string, DateTime> LastSuccessfulTokenFetchTimestamps = new Dictionary<string, DateTime>();
    #endregion

    #region Properties

    // this is used to provide information about current reporting instance
    private IMsiProjectSourceService MsiProjectSourceService { get; }
    private ILoggingService Logger { get; }
    #endregion

    #region Constructor
    public MsiRestClientService(ILoggingService logger, IMsiProjectSourceService msiProjectSourceService)
    {
        Logger = logger;
        MsiProjectSourceService = msiProjectSourceService;
    }
    #endregion

    #region Private methods

    private TokenInfo GetProjectSourceTokenInfo(string projectSourceName)
    {
        lock (LockSync)
        {
            return MsiProjectSourceToTokenMap.ContainsKey(projectSourceName)
                ? MsiProjectSourceToTokenMap[projectSourceName]
                : null;
        }
    }

    private void SetProjectSourceTokenInfo(string projectSourceName, TokenInfo token)
    {
        lock (LockSync)
        {
            MsiProjectSourceToTokenMap[projectSourceName] = token;
        }
    }

    private DateTime? GetLastSuccessfulTokenFetchTimestamp(string projectSourceName)
    {
        lock (LockSync)
        {
            return LastSuccessfulTokenFetchTimestamps.ContainsKey(projectSourceName)
                ? LastSuccessfulTokenFetchTimestamps[projectSourceName]
                : (DateTime?) null;
        }
    }

    private void SetLastSuccessfulTokenFetchTimestamp(string projectSourceName, DateTime dateTime)
    {
        lock (LockSync)
        {
            LastSuccessfulTokenFetchTimestamps[projectSourceName] = dateTime;
        }
    }

    private (MsiRestClient, CookieContainer) GetMsiRestClientInfo(string projectSourceName, CookieContainer cookies = null)
    {
        // using provided cookies if any, otherwise creating new ones
        CookieContainer actualCookies = cookies ?? new CookieContainer();
        var msiHttpClientHandler = new HttpClientHandler { CookieContainer = actualCookies };
        var msiHttpClient = new HttpClient(msiHttpClientHandler);
        var msiRestClient = new MsiRestClient(msiHttpClient)
        {
            // this is required before the generator does not fetch the URL correctly
            BaseUrl = MsiProjectSourceService.GetMsiProjectSourceRestApiUrl(projectSourceName)
        };

        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(msiRestClient.BaseUrl))
            throw new ArgumentException($"No MSI Rest Api URL found for project source {projectSourceName}");

        return (msiRestClient, actualCookies);
    }

    private async Task<bool> RefreshToken(string projectSourceName)
    {
        // do not refresh if the token if it has just been successfully been refreshed recently
        // this is done to avoid mass-refresh when multiple clients want to use the service to query MSI

        var credentials = MsiProjectSourceService.GetMsiProjectSourceCredentials(projectSourceName);
        if (credentials == null)
        {
            Logger.LogError($"Failed to get credentials for project source {projectSourceName}");
            return false;
        }

        await GetNewTokenSemaphore.WaitAsync();
        try
        {
            DateTime lastSuccessfulTokenFetchTimestamp =
                GetLastSuccessfulTokenFetchTimestamp(projectSourceName) ?? new DateTime(2000, 1, 1);

            int interval = (int) (DateTime.Now - lastSuccessfulTokenFetchTimestamp).TotalSeconds;
            if (interval < TokenRefreshCoolDownPeriod)
                return true;

            var (msiRestClient, cookies) = GetMsiRestClientInfo(projectSourceName);
            var authData = new AuthRequest
            {
                Username = credentials.Username,
                Password = credentials.Password
            };

            try
            {
                await msiRestClient.PostLoginAsync(authData);
            }
            //TODO: replace with ApiException when NullReferenceException is solved
            catch (Exception exc)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Failed to authenticate for MSI project source: " + exc);
                throw;
            }

            TokenInfo ti = new TokenInfo {Token = msiRestClient.Token, Cookies = cookies};
            SetProjectSourceTokenInfo(projectSourceName, ti);
            SetLastSuccessfulTokenFetchTimestamp(projectSourceName, DateTime.Now);
            return true;
        }
        finally
        {
            GetNewTokenSemaphore.Release();
        }
    }

    // checks if token information is available and reauthenticates if needed. Also, allows to forcefully reauthenticate (e.g. caller knows about a failure)
    private async Task<TokenInfo> EnsureTokenInfo(string projectSourceName, bool force)
    {
        var tokenInfo = GetProjectSourceTokenInfo(projectSourceName);
        if (force || tokenInfo == null)
        {
            await RefreshToken(projectSourceName);
            tokenInfo = GetProjectSourceTokenInfo(projectSourceName);
        }
        if (tokenInfo == null)
        {
            throw new ApplicationException(
                $"Failed to get cached info for project source {projectSourceName}. Should not happen since token info was just refreshed");
        }

        return tokenInfo;
    }

    private string HandleRestApiCallException(Exception e, int trial)
    {
        string errorMessage = $"Unexpected exception during Rest Api Call {trial}";
        if (e is ApiException apiExc)
        {
            return $"ExecuteWithTokenRefresh failed #{trial}: Response = {apiExc.Response}, Code = {apiExc.StatusCode}";
        }
        if (e is ArgumentNullException)
        {
            errorMessage = $"ExecuteWithTokenRefresh failed #{trial}: {e.Message}";
            Logger.LogInfo(errorMessage);
            return errorMessage;
        }
        if (e is NullReferenceException)
        {
            errorMessage = "Null reference exception received while executing ExecuteWithTokenRefresh - did you fix ApiException code?";
            Logger.LogError(errorMessage);
            return errorMessage;
        }

        return errorMessage;
    }

    private async Task<ValidationResult<TRes>> ExecuteWithTokenRefresh<TRes>(string projectSourceName, 
        Func<MsiRestClient, string, Task<TRes>> requestFunc)
    {
        var tokenInfo = await EnsureTokenInfo(projectSourceName, false);

        // creating a REST client based on data got from authentication (including cookies)
        var (msiRestClient, _) = GetMsiRestClientInfo(projectSourceName, tokenInfo.Cookies);

        try
        {
            var result = await requestFunc(msiRestClient, tokenInfo.Token);

            // no exception means that it successfully completed
            return new ValidationResult<TRes> {Payload = result};
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            HandleRestApiCallException(e, 1);
        }

        // error is most probably caused by an authentication / transient REST service -> retrying
        tokenInfo = await EnsureTokenInfo(projectSourceName, true);
        var (msiRestClientBis, _) = GetMsiRestClientInfo(projectSourceName, tokenInfo.Cookies);

        string errorMessage;
        try
        {
            var result = await requestFunc(msiRestClientBis, tokenInfo.Token);

            // no exception means that it successfully completed
            return new ValidationResult<TRes> { Payload = result };
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            errorMessage = HandleRestApiCallException(e, 2);
        }

        return new ValidationResult<TRes>
        {
            IsError = true,
            Message = errorMessage
        };
    }
    #endregion

    #region Public methods

    public async Task<TokenInfo> GetTokenInfo(string projectSourceName)
    {
        bool refreshResult = await RefreshToken(projectSourceName);
        if (!refreshResult)
            return null;

        return GetProjectSourceTokenInfo(projectSourceName);
    }

    // all actual calls that do not deal with authentication or retrial simply use ExecuteWithTokenRefresh to wrap the actual call
    public async Task<ValidationResult<SessionInfo>> GetCurrentUserSessionInfo(string projectSourceName)
    {
        return await ExecuteWithTokenRefresh(projectSourceName, 
            async (msiRestClient, token) => await msiRestClient.SessionSessionIdUserInfoGetAsync(token));
    }

    #endregion
}
```

#### Usage

```
[HttpGet("[action]")]
public async Task<ActionResult<ValidationResult<SessionInfo>>> GetCurrentUserSessionInfo(string localName = null)
{
    Logger.LogInfo("Test/GetCurrentUserSessionInfo called");

    var result = await MsiRestClientService.GetCurrentUserSessionInfo(localName);
    return new ActionResult<ValidationResult<SessionInfo>>(result);
}
```

Am I on the right track?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Review

- Don't use regions to group members by type. This is redundant grouping. ([Regions pattern or anti-pattern?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/53086/are-regions-an-antipattern-or-code-smell))
- Use proper naming conventions and casing of variables. `LockSync` is generally called `syncRoot`. `GetNewTokenSemaphore` indicates a method name, rename it to `newTokenMutex`. It's a mutex because you use the semaphore as a mutex.
- Prefer `TryGetValue` over the two-phase `ContainsKey` + `Indexer` lookup on a `Dictionary`. Refactor `GetProjectSourceTokenInfo` and `GetLastSuccessfulTokenFetchTimestamp` to use this method instead.
- `GetMsiRestClientInfo` is a factory method, so rename it to `CreateMsiRestClientInfo`.
- `GetMsiRestClientInfo` creates instances of `HttpClient`. This class uses a socket connection and is `IDisposable` to manage its connection with it. But you never dispose instances of this class. Also, creating instances all the time might lead to an influx in socket connections. ([HttpClient Considerations](https://aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/)) I suggest to also provide a cache of instances, given the cookies and a dispose strategy.
- `RefreshToken` mixes sandbox (`return false`) with error-prone (`throw`) statements. There is no clear specification what this method should return when. It seems a mess.
- Using `DateTime.Now` to validate cache expiration is bad practice. Prefer a strategy that does not rely on your system's local time. An option is to consider `StopWatch`.